# How to view balance of ERC1155 in Metamask?

Tags: solidity, metamask, erc-1155

I've deployed an `ERC1155 Token` via openzeppelin wizard and on importing that contract in `Metamask` I am facing this following issue

[image]

How can I fix this?

Here's my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Burnable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC1155, Ownable, ERC1155Burnable {
    constructor() ERC1155("") {}

    function setURI(string memory newuri) public onlyOwner {
        _setURI(newuri);
    }

    function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mint(account, id, amount, data);
    }

    function mintBatch(address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory amounts, bytes memory data)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        _mintBatch(to, ids, amounts, data);
    }
}
```

Here is the contract address `0x0d69A6F6898F69Ad5730a11B9BB14A0547C16C8E`

Do I need to change anything in contract?

Please lemme know !!

Comment: share the contract code and address

Comment: I am using the code as it is from the openzeppalin wizard

Comment: check now! I've updated the question

Comment: If your tokens are visible on opensea then that's okayy. metamask doesn't support NFTs fully 
you can try to check on the mobile app once

Comment: The main issue is that for famous ERC1155 NFTs its showing in metamask

Comment: You may improve the contract
By adding a name and symbol for the token.
One more thing is trying to import the tokens into a mobile wallet. maybe it will support.